# How to check if someone else has blocked me?

Tags: macos, ios, messages

For various reasons, I believe that someone has blocked me in iMessage, but I am not 100% sure.

Right now, it shows the message is delivered.

Is there a way to see if they blocked me, or if they have just not read it yet?

Comment: The whole idea of blocking is that you never know. They might just have switched off 'read receipts'

Comment: @Tetsujin True. I was hoping there was a definite way to figure it out, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no definite way to tell.

However, if a person does not respond after a long period of time, they most likely have blocked you.

Comment: Or they're just ignoring you, with similar effect to blocking.

Comment: So the messages will deliver?

Comment: @User Yup, correct.

Comment: I think when people block each other, messages send as SMS.